# Micrometer - WebMvcTagsContributor not adding custom tags

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

I'm trying to add custom tags - the path variables and their values from each request - to each metric micrometer generates. I'm using spring-boot with java 16.

From my research i've found that creating a bean of type `WebMvcTagsContributor` alows me to do just that.

This is the code

```
public class CustomWebMvcTagsContributor implements WebMvcTagsContributor {

  private static int PRINT_ERROR_COUNTER = 0;

  @Override
  public Iterable<Tag> getTags(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      Object handler,
      Throwable exception) {
    return Tags.of(getAllTags(request));
  }

  private static List<Tag> getAllTags(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Object attributesMapObject = request.getAttribute(View.PATH_VARIABLES);
    if (isNull(attributesMapObject)) {
      attributesMapObject = request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);

      if (isNull(attributesMapObject)) {
        attributesMapObject = extractPathVariablesFromURI(request);
      }
    }

    if (nonNull(attributesMapObject)) {
      return getPathVariablesTags(attributesMapObject);
    }

    return List.of();
  }

  private static Object extractPathVariablesFromURI(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Long currentUserId = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserId().orElse(null);
    try {
      URI uri = new URI(request.getRequestURI());
      String path = uri.getPath(); //get the path
      UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate((String) request.getAttribute(
          HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)); //create template
      return uriTemplate.match(path); //extract values form template
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("[Error on 3rd attempt]", e);
    }

    return null;
  }

  private static List<Tag> getPathVariablesTags(Object attributesMapObject) {
    try {
      Long currentUserId = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserId().orElse(null);

      if (nonNull(attributesMapObject)) {
        var attributesMap = (Map<String, Object>) attributesMapObject;
        List<Tag> tags = attributesMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(stringObjectEntry -> Tag.of(stringObjectEntry.getKey(),
                String.valueOf(stringObjectEntry.getValue())))
            .toList();

          log.warn("[CustomTags] [{}]", CommonUtils.toJson(tags));
        return tags;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if (PRINT_ERROR_COUNTER < 5) {
        log.error("[Error while getting attributes map object]", e);
        PRINT_ERROR_COUNTER++;
      }
    }
    return List.of();
  }

  @Override
  public Iterable<Tag> getLongRequestTags(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```
  @Bean
  public WebMvcTagsContributor webMvcTagsContributor() {
    return new CustomWebMvcTagsContributor();
  }
```

In order to test this, i've created a small spring boot app, added an endpoint to it. It works just fine.

The problem is when I add this code to the production app.

The metrics generates are the default ones and i can't figure out why.

What can I check to see why the tags are not added?

```
local test project

http_server_requests_seconds_count {exception="None", method="GET",id="123",outcome="Success",status="200",test="test",uri="/test/{id}/compute/{test}",)1.0

in prod - different (& bigger) app
http_server_requests_seconds_count {exception="None", method="GET",outcome="Success",status="200",uri="/api/{something}/test",)1.0
```

What i've tried and didn't work

- Created a bean that implemented `WebMvcTagsProvider` - this one had an odd behaviour - it wasn't creating metrics for endpoints that had path variables in the path - though in my local test project it worked as expected
- I added that log there in order to see what the extra tags are but doesn't seem to reach there as i don't see anything in the logs - i know, you might say that the current user id stops it, but it's not that.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to test this, i've created a small spring boot app, added an endpoint to it. It works just fine.
> The problem is when I add this code to the production app.
> The metrics generates are the default ones and i can't figure out why.

You can check the `/actuator/beans` endpoint to see if your bean is created but since there is nothing specific in your setup it should.

Do you happen to use a Java agent like datadog/azure app insights, opentelemetry? If so, try to remove it and check again.